# How do I use XPath expressions when querying from a XML attribute in a Oracle database

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, xpath

I am using XPath to query a database. I am having trouble trying to return two values. I have a single attribute table which is an XML element called `Book`. I could find the title of all books but I don't know how to find the title AND year of all books. Below shows `Book`:

```
<Book>
<Title></Title>
<Year></Year>
<Author></Author>
</Book>
```

To find the title of all books I would use:

```
/book/title.
```

How would I find the title and the year of all books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the `self::` axis to select multiple children of `Book`:

```
/Book/*[self::Title or self::Year]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union:

```
/book/title | /book/year
```